# how to copy files to C:\temp in VS 2008 setup project?

Tags: c#, .net, installation, windows-installer

I am learning use VS 2008 setup project to create MSI installer for our C# application. The target system is Windows 7 embedded. Did some research online and couldn't find answers.

Because the application will be installed on Win7 machine. We need to put some files in C:\temp folder for read and write. how can I copy those files into C:\temp during the installation?

thanks,

Comment: You may need to use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP")` rather than hardcode the path.

Comment: Odd question.  The point of using embedded is to use the system builder to create your own image.  Why not use the builder to put the files where they need to go?  Do you actually want to support installs after the image is created?

Comment: that is next step. for now we will do install on top of embedded, then create an image with everything in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your setup project:

- Bring up the File System view.
- Right-click on the pane, select *Add Special Folder -> Custom Folder*.
- Right-click on that folder and select "Properties".
- Change the *Default Location* property to "C:\temp".

Now add files to that folder in the project as appropriate.

Is there any reason the folder has to be, literally, "C:\temp"? That's not guaranteed to exist on every Windows system (though it sounds like you have control over your deployments).

Comment: I tested with your answer, it will actually create one for you if not exist. I should ask here earlier to save me hours reading online which turns out nothing.